# Geometric locus of points.

Tags: geometry

The vertices of triangles having a common base and congruent altitudes.
I came up with the picture below.[image: fig]

I we consider the segment AB as our common base, and all altitudes length congruent the segment CB, then the geometric locus of points is the line HC and IJ. Is this correct? I came up with two sets of points which are the two lines. But I thought the geometric locus of points is a unique set of points that satisfy some condition. But the two lines I got satisfy the given condition but not unique.

Comment: It is a unique set of points. They happen not to be "connected" to each other.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You mean that if a set of points is not connected to other set of points, then each set is considered as unique?

Comment: The locus is the *union* of the two lines. Or if you prefer (I do) it consists of two lines.

Comment: If your question is "From the given line segment AB, find the locus of the variable point (say G) such that the area of of triangle GAB is constant.", then the left end of H and the right end of C should  also form part of your answer. The same is true for J and I too.

Comment: @eChung00: You are welcome. Note that by "two lines" I mean two *full* lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

André already pointed out the key aspect in his comments, but I'd like to get this question out of the unanswered queue.

The locus is the set of all points satisfying given constraints. In your case, any point on either of the two (infinite) lines will satisfy the requirements, as you already pointed out yourself. Therefore the locus is the union of all these points, i.e. the union of the two lines you described. So the locus consists of both lines taken together. As such it is unique.

Answer (score -1):

Andre and MvG already answered this question very well. But still I want to add something from the Master Euclid:

If you study the Proposition 37 of Euclid's Book 1, it directly relates to this question. His proposition states that "Triangles which are on the same bases and between the same parallels (lines) are equal to one another."

You may be worried about the converse of this theorem. But its converse really holds true. If you like to further investigate the converse or related theorems, please see this https://mathematicshub.wordpress.com/2015/08/29/proposition-37-euclids-elements/.

Also, this is a question, that I saw in the Kiselev's Geometry Book 1 as question number 199. I've solved a lot of questions from this book. I also want someone who is interested in matching the answers of the questions as the author never wrote any solution manual.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to the question the OP is asking, which is about the meaning of the word "locus".

Comment: "The vertices of triangles having a common base and congruent altitudes." doesn't it relate to what I stated? I read the full question indeed, but shared what I had in my mind. Don't know why you -1 me.

Comment: Still you think its irrelevant. I can remove it.